# How to use scrollStrategy in MatDialog?

Tags: angular, scroll, dialog, angular-material

I tried to make a scroll for a dialog in reposition strategy, but it doesn't work for me.

```
const scrollStrategy = this.overlay.scrollStrategies.reposition();
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open( DialogOverviewExampleDialog, { scrollStrategy } );
```

[The full example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ss6wkf-smk1ws?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts)

I expect that during scrolling the whole dialog(element `.cdk-overlay-pane`) will move

[Almost right behavior](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ss6wkf-zzzqdt?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts)

Answer (score 86):

If you want to scroll the content of the dialog then you have to use the `<mat-dialog-content>` tag, or use the directive mat-dialog-content in your div element.
In your example try the following instead:

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Hi {{data.name}}</h1>
<mat-dialog-content> <!-- instead of your <div>  or use <div mat-dialog-content> -->
  <p>What's your favorite animal!!!!!!!</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <p>What's your favorite animal!!!!!!</p>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.animal">
  </mat-form-field>
</mat-dialog-content> <!-- instead of your </div> -->
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">No Thanks</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>
```

And now your dialog content should have a scroll on the side.
Read more about the *Scrollable content container of a dialog* on:

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogContent

Comment: Not so... I want to scroll the whole dialog. Look at [the example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ss6wkf-zzzqdt)

Comment: @dirbacke Bisons

Comment: This answer is not about the author's question.

Comment: Please help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790584/why-i-cant-scroll-down-on-a-big-popup-dialog-in-angular?noredirect=1#comment105776607_59790584

Comment: @constantant to scroll the whole dialog, put the <mat-dialog-content> outside the very outer div of your dialog. The scrollbar will still be on the dialog but imo it looks better that way so you scroll the dialog not scroll the page.

Answer (score 68):

I tried this way,

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(LoginModalComponent, {
      autoFocus: false,
      maxHeight: '90vh' //you can adjust the value as per your view
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Not clear on what the author wants.

Answer (score 17):

Hi try to put this on your style.css or style.scss

```
.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: auto;
  pointer-events: auto;  
}
```

Comment: Make sure that pointer-events has !important if you don't scope the class more. But here is what I did, quite like yours:
.cdk-overlay-container > .cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  pointer-events: auto;
}. But notice the scope of the cdk-overlay-container

Answer (score 9):

Had a similar issue. Found that this works with Angular 12 and above.

```
import { ScrollStrategy, ScrollStrategyOptions } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

scrollStrategy: ScrollStrategy;

constructor(private readonly sso: ScrollStrategyOptions) {
   this.scrollStrategy = this.sso.noop(); // or close()/block()/reposition()
}
```

And pass it in to MatDialogConfig object as: (See docks [ScrollStrategyOptions](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#ScrollStrategyOptions))

```
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(
    DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {scrollStrategy: this.scrollStrategy }
  );
```

This stackblitz helped me to understand my problem - [ScrollStrategyOptions](https://stackblitz.com/edit/scroll-strategy-block-5xmwap?file=app%2Fsidenav-open-close-example.ts)

Answer (score 4):

Since https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/11235, `.mat-dialog-container` got `max-height: inherit` which should solve your problem.

Setting `maxHeight: window.innerHeight + 'px'` on the dialog configuration prevents the dialog from growing bigger than the screen.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a similar solution as OP. The trick in the provided [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ss6wkf-zzzqdt?file=styles.css) is to set `overflow:auto` on the `.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper`.

Add this css to your styles **(not inside the dialog's css)**:

Altough there's a slight issue, without auto pointer-events scrolling does not work on current chrome version and with auto pointer-events, closing via backdrop click does not work.
(will update if i find a solution)

```css
.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  pointer-events: auto;  // needed for chrome but prevents backdrop click close
}
```

If you want to prevent scrolling on the back scenery i.e. parent component you <strike>could set `overflow: hidden` on the parent as long as the dialog is open.</strike>

.. just remove the scroll strategy from the example.

Answer (score 1):

compare all the files difference.
there is extra css in style.css

```css
.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
  pointer-events: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.cdk-overlay-pane {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: I noticed the same thing. The `overflow: auto` piece allows it to scroll, and everything else forces it to fit better on the screen.

Comment: I know. I am an author of the code :) I would like to know how to implement the same behavior without the css modification. I hope you have noticed non-working background clicking which is a problem of this solution.

Comment: Another problem with this approach is that when trying open a dialog inside a dialog, it shows the second one outside the viewport.

Comment: Related to this, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65406048/remove-previous-mat-dialogs-css-from-dom

Answer (score 0):

Its enough to add the two attributes below.

```
.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  pointer-events: auto;  
}
```

Comment: The backdrop clicking does not work in that case. Look at the initial example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ss6wkf-zzzqdt?file=styles.css

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mat-dialog-content` selector in order to create a scrollable content container for the dialog.

https://next.material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogContent

Answer (score -1):

```
let dialogRef = this.matDialog.open(MyComponent, {
   height: '100%',
   autoFocus: false,
});
```

[image]

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.