# How to add scrollbar to my dialog in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog, scrollview, scrollbar

I am opening a dialog window using the following function:

```
  doOutput(){
    this.dialog.open(NgxChartsComponent ) ; 

  }
```

And the HTML code of my `NgxChartsComponent` is:

```
<!-- The chart type goes in here -->

<div> This is a visual representation of a line chart</div>
<div style="display: inline-block">
    <ngx-charts-line-chart
      [view]="view"
      [scheme]="colorScheme"
      [results]="multi"
      [gradient]="gradient"
      [xAxis]="showXAxis"
      [yAxis]="showYAxis"
      [legend]="showLegend"
      [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
      [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
      [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
      [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
      [autoScale]="autoScale"
      [timeline]="timeline"
      (select)="onSelect($event)">
    </ngx-charts-line-chart>
  </div>

    <br>
    <div> This is a visual representation of a area chart</div>

    <div style="display: inline-block">
    <ngx-charts-area-chart
      [view]="view"
      [scheme]="colorScheme"
      [results]="multi"
      [gradient]="gradient"
      [xAxis]="showXAxis"
      [yAxis]="showYAxis"
      [legend]="showLegend"
      [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
      [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
      [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
      [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
      [autoScale]="autoScale"
      (select)="onSelect($event)">
    </ngx-charts-area-chart>
    </div>


    <br>
    <div> This is a visual representation of a pie chart</div>

    <div style="display: inline-block">
    <ngx-charts-pie-chart
    [view]="view"
    [scheme]="colorScheme"
    [results]="single"
    [legend]="showLegend"
    [explodeSlices]="explodeSlices"
    [labels]="showLabels"
    [doughnut]="doughnut"
    [gradient]="gradient"
    (select)="onSelect($event)">
  </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
</div>
```

I use `MatDialog` and `MatDialogRef` to create my dialog and it works well but I must zoom out the screen to see the full content of the dialog and there is no scroll facility for that! Please help me know how can I add scroll to my popup dialog window?

Comment: How do you make the popup?. Sure ngbModal has an option to scrollable, and I supouse material dialog too

Comment: @Eliseo: I use `MatDialog`.

Comment: Maybe you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651320/how-to-use-scrollstrategy-in-matdialog

Comment: @standby954: I can't understand what do exactly should I do? Should I put my html code inside of a mat-dialog tag?

Answer (score 1):

You should use MatDialogContent to define your scrollable content. Like that:

```
<mat-dialog-content>
   <!-- put your lage content here -->
</mat-dialog-content>
```

You can see the first example here https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples

Answer (score 0):

I think what you just need is a simple `overflow: scroll;` in you dialog's css

Comment: What do u mean by my dialog css? Do you mean the css code of `Ngxcharts.component`?